SensorEventListener onSensorChanged() is no longer called every 10ms with API Level 33/34
The android SensorEventListener onSensorChanged() method used to be called very exact in time to what was requested by sensorManager.registerListener(fastestListener, accelerometer, 100);
Now, with API Level 33/34, I sometimes get the onSensorChanged() called every 140ms, and sometimes every 0.3ms
I am trying to process accelerometer data.
I have this code in the class implementing SensorEventListener:
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor my = event.sensor;
        if (my.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if (this.timestampAccelerometerPrev > 0) {
                this.timeDiffAccelerometer = System.nanoTime() - timestampAccelerometerPrev;
            }
            this.timestampAccelerometerPrev = System.nanoTime();
            Log.d(TAG, "Accelerometer Sampling diff: " + (double) timeDiffAccelerometer / (double) 1000000);


Which outputs these types of difference time values:
10.585208
10.02349
10.007396
10.344322
9.903906
9.971875
10.321146
9.600781
55.639427
0.26776
0.140521
0.126875
0.120052
23.354166
0.194375
14.8075
0.139896
6.359844
14.531875
6.128177
10.092968
10.712708
9.95151
10.404323
10.021511


It can be device-specific, did you check on different devices?

I did, and it did not appear on very old Andoird 8 device. But I don't think my Samsung Galaxy A05S 2024 is broken?
